# Google Earth Engine: I am only interested in the values for a specific day each year, how do I accomplish that?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an imageCollection from CHIRPS, which provides world-wide data over daily precipitation for the past 30 years. I am only interested in the precipitation for the day December 20th each of those 30 years (which should return only 30 points), how would I filter for that day? I have a previously specified boundary as well.

```
var chirpsColl = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY")
                  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(365,'day_of_year'))
                  .filterDate('2010-01-01','2018-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(Dalarna);
//print(chirpsColl);
var chirpsMean = chirpsColl.mean().clip(Dalarna);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will filter the image collection first on the month December, and then on the 20th day of December:

```
var chirpsColl = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY")
                  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(12, 12, 'month'))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(20, 20, 'day_of_month'))
                  .filterBounds(Dalarna);
```

Note that day_of_year filter won't be appropiate for years with and without the 29th of February.